# How the answer of this for loop is 5?

Tags: c

I was practicing my C skills online. And I got a question like:

What is the output of this program?

```
void main(){
int i;
for(i=1;i++<=1;i++)
i++;
printf("%d",i);
}
```

The answer was 5. But I thought the for loop would execute endlessly. As the i will be incremented on each iteration and i will be **never less than or equal to 1**. how come 5 will be the output of this program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: The proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What makes you think the OP is using a hosted system compiler? See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518)

Comment: Why should it execute endlessly if you assume the condition will never be true? If your assumption was correct, it should not execute at all.

Comment: @Lundin - I'm just a simple man, all I can do is read the standard unless the OP provides specifics. Perhaps we need to drop you same comment below each referencing [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Then you can read the title of chapter 5.1.2.2.

Comment: So you are just covering the case of the 5.1.2.1 - being everything else and implementation defined. I get what you are saying, and there are more and more embedded systems out there (now how many of them chose a `void main()` implementation -- no telling)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained by the sequence of events:

```
i = 1; // for init
i++ <= 1 ? true // for condition, i evaluates as 1 but is made into i = 2 after the expression
i++; // inside for body, makes i = 3
i++; // for increment, makes i = 4
i++ <= 1 ? false // for condition again, i evaluates as 4 but is made into i = 5 after the expression
// condition is false, for loop ends, i = 5
```

Perhaps you are forgetting that the `for` condition, although false, is still executed to verify that before the program decides the loop is terminated.

Answer (score 4):

`i` is incremented four times before the [`for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for) loop exits.

- Twice in the `for` condition check (formally `cond_expression`). Since you are using postfix increment, the first time `i` will be `1` when the condition is checked. It is only on the second check, `i` will be `2`.
- Once in the increment (formally `iteration_expression`)
- Once more in the body (formally `loop_statement`) of the `for` loop.

As the initial value of `i` is `1`, this brings its value to `5`.

**Note:**
- `cond_expression` is evaluated **before** the loop body. If the result of the expression is zero, the loop statement is exited immediately.
- `iteration_expression` is evaluated **after** the loop body and its result is discarded. After evaluating `iteration_expression`, control is transferred to `cond_expression`.

Comment: @MrAlpha:  I update the answer. Please see if this clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

> As the i will be incremented on each iteration and i will be never less than or equal to 1. how come 5 will be the output of this program?

How can `i` never be less than or equal to `1` when it's initialised with a value of `1`?

Did you intend to pre-increment `i`?

That would be:

```
for (i=1; ++1 <= 1; i++)
```

But you seem to misunderstand the nature of the conditional expression here, with a `for` loop you are repeating a block of code until a condition is met, in this case do `code` while `i++ <= 1`.

If you do

```
for (i=1; ++i <= 1; i++)
```

`i` will be > 1 on the first iteration and nothing will happen.